# return String vs Integer vs undefined vs null

Tags: javascript

Why does javascript prefers to return a `String` over any other choices ?

Consider the following snippet.

```
var arr = ['Hello1', 'Hello2', 'Hello3'];

Array.prototype.item = function(x) {
   return this[x] || null || 'aïe' || 12 || undefined ;
};

console.log( arr.item(43) ); // returns aïe
```

**I intentionally called a non-existent array element.**

However i cannot understand why does `arr.item(43)` returns the `String` ? Why not `null` or `undefined` or even `12` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because `this[x]` is `undefined`, which is falsy, and so is `null`.

The `||` operator returns the first "truthy" value it finds, and stops its evaluation at that point.

If no "truthy" value is found, it returns the result of the last operand evaluated.

There are a total of 6 "falsey" values. They are...

1. `false`
2. `undefined`
3. `null`
4. `""`
5. `NaN`
6. `0`

*Everything* else is considered truthy.

So your expression will be evaluated as...

```
//   v--falsey            v--truthy! return it!
((((this[x] || null) || 'aïe') || 12) || undefined);
//               ^--falsey         ^--------^---these are not evaluated at all
```

Or you could look at it like this:

```
(
  (
    (
      (this[x] || null) // return null
            /* (null */ || 'aïe') // return 'aïe' and stop evaluating
                                || 12) 
                                      || undefined);
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, the `||` returns the last evaluated expression. In which case when one is *truthy*, it will return that.

Comment: @alex: Hmmm... yes, but the first "truthy" expression *is* the last evaluated. Perhaps I didn't stress the short-circuiting explicitly enough. I'll update.

Comment: Stephen Colbert would be proud of the truthiness in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

The statement

```
return this[x] || null || 'aïe' || 12 || undefined ;
```

will evaluate the subexpressions left to right, and will return the first subexpression that does not evaluate to *false*. The non-existent element evaluates to *false* as it's undefined, and `null` is *false* by definition. That leaves the string as the first non-*false* subexpression, so that's what you get.

Answer (score 3):

The code `a || b` is roughly equivalent to `a ? a : b`, or this slightly more verbose code:

```
if (a) {
    result = a;
} else {
    result = b;
}
```

Since `||` is [left-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) the expression `a || b || c` is evaluated as `(a || b) || c`.

---

So in simple terms this means that the `||` operator when chained returns the first operand that is "truthy", or else the last element.

This feature can be useful for providing defaults when you have missing values:

```
var result = f() || g() || defaultValue;
```

You could read this as: Get the result of f(). If it's a falsey value, then try g(). If that also gives a falsey value, then use `defaultValue`.

Answer (score 1):

The string is the first truthy value in the chain of or's. Simples.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is evaluating in order from left to right.

If you were to modify to this:

```
return this[x] || null || 12 || 'aïe' || undefined ;
```

Your answer would be 12.

Answer (score 0):

`return this[x] || null || 'aïe' || 12 || undefined` will not return one of those. It is supposed to return the result of the expression `this[x] || null || 'aïe' || 12 || undefined` - I believe it will return a boolean value.