# What does this JS code mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

I stumbled upon this line, and can't seem to figure out what it means

```
var G = G || {};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `G` is currently ***any*** "falsey" value, then the object literal will be assigned to `G`.

The "falsey" values are...

- `undefined`
- `null`
- `''`
- `NaN`
- `false`
- `0`

The operator being used is the *logical OR* operator.

The way it works is that it evaluates its left operand first. If that operand has a "truthy" value *(any non-falsey value)*, it returns it, and doesn't evaluate *(short-circuits)* the second operand.

If the left operand was "falsey", then it returns its right operand, irrespective of its value.

---

Example where `G` is falsey...

```
//      v--- Evaluate G. The value of G is the "falsey" value undefined...
var G = G || {};
//            ^--- ...so evaluate and return the right hand operand.
```

Example where `G` is truthy...

```
G = 123;

//      v--- Evaluate G. The value of G is a "truthy" value 123...
var G = G || {};
//      ^--- ...so return 123, and do not evaluate the right hand operand.
```

Comment: That's what I guessed, but it makes no sense to me, because of the "var" part. I mean, the G variable is defined in the same line, what's the point of giving it the value of G||{}? Isn't it the same as var G = {}; ?

Comment: @Loupax: Yes you're right, if there's no way that `G` could have already been initialized, then the `||` doesn't have much point. Sometimes people unnecessarily redeclare variables, or declare variables that are already declared as parameters, so maybe that's what's happening here.

Comment: ...note that `undefined` is the default value for declared variables.

Comment: Doesn't undefined || {} == false? Empty objects evaluate to true? That's something I didn't know...

Comment: @Loupax: Any object will give a "truthy" evaluation. You should note that truthyness is a boolean evaluation, while `==` is not. `Boolean({}); // true` `Boolean(undefined); // false`

Comment: Now I'm more confused than before o_O I mean, I know what the line does, but how it works? Shouldn't var G = G || {} give G the value true instead of empty object?

Comment: @Loupax: No, it evaluates the operand as "truthy" or "falsey", but it always returns the operand itself. So lets say the first operand is `{foo:'bar'}`, it evaluates its "truthyness", decides that it is indeed "truthy", and so it returns the object. So while it *considers* its truthyness, it never *coerces* the operand to a boolean.

Comment: And that explains everything! Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Loupax: You're welcome. You should note that these operators may be combined, in which case, it works from left to right until it returns the first "truthy" operand found, or the last operand. [Here's a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8578135/1106925) I gave that demonstrates the behavior when you have multiple `||` in a row.

Answer (score 5):

G = G, and if G does not exist, create it as an empty object.

Answer (score 5):

G is G or a new object if G is <del>not defined</del> ["falsy"](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

Comment: Oh I get it! So in case I've already declared G on other part of the script, G won't be overwritten?

Comment: Right. Also, as suggested by @am-not-i-am it's not just " not declared", but "undefined", "false", etc.